# where does common/global data go in mvvm?

Tags: mvvm

I'm trying to get my head around mvvm and came up with a test application that I think will give me a good foundation. Suppose my application has a service that goes out every minute and gets the latest flight arrival and departure information at an airport. Now suppose I have 3 different views: InboundView, OutboundView and GateView. The Inbound and Outbound views would simply display the various flight details for inbound and outbound flights that I'm sure we've all seen on the flight boards in the airport. The GateView would display similar flight information but might be sorted by gate # instead of flight #.

So the model for the Flight object would contain the flight data details as well as an instance of a Gate object that would be updated appropriately once a flight arrives.

So all 3 views are using the same flight data service and I know I can pass an instance of that service to each VM but then I'd need to hook up the appropriate INPC events at each view model and that seems less than ideal as the number of views/vms increases.

Right now, each VM uses a ListCollectionView wrapped around the passed in collection of flight data and I just sort/filter based on inbound/outbound, etc.. but I was hoping to incorporate the service results into a sort of parent view model that would then pass a reference to itself along to the sub-views and then I could just handle all the INPC, etc.. events at the parent view model level and those will automatically trickle down to each of the subviews if data on a particular flight changes (such as its gate) instead of having to handle that separately in each of the VMs.

I've looked into the Messenger framework for MVVM Light but it still seems like each of the sub-VMs would have to register for the message and respond to it individually.

Does that make sense? Am I on the right track here?

Answer (score 0):

> So all 3 views are using the same flight data service and I know I can pass an instance of that service to each VM but then I'd need to hook up the appropriate INPC events at each view model and that seems less than ideal as the number of views/vms increases.

You don't necessarily have to do this, if the "service" implements INotifyPropertyChanged.  Remember, you can bind to a property within a property, ie:  `{Binding Path=FlightService.Gate}` or whatever, which may work.  (It's difficult to know your requirements here, though.)

> I've looked into the Messenger framework for MVVM Light but it still seems like each of the sub-VMs would have to register for the message and respond to it individually.

Yes, if you wanted to use a messaging framework, you would need this to be handled in each of the ViewModels.  Alternatively, you could use some form of service location or constructor injection to "pull in" the flight service.  The latter is my personal preference here.

The advantage of handling this in each VM is that each VM will likely want to handle things somewhat differently (otherwise, why is there more than 1?).  By pulling a reference to the service in via IoC, you can handle this anyway you need to.